# display: flex; has no effect in header

Tags: html, css

Cannot make the logo and text appear in a row on header tag of webpage by applying flex in CSS. My code is along with this post and also attached output on web browser (Chrome) at the end..

Is this problem caused by a mistake in below code. New to webdesign, can anyone find what's wrong with my code. I want to apply flex on `<header>` tag so that img and `<nav>` content will be in a row. But that's not happening. See the webpage screenshot at the post end.

```css
.container {
  width: 1024px;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

header {
  background-color: #63BC7D; 
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

main {
  /*background-color: #179E3F; */
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/

}

.cards {
  background-color: #AC1149;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 

}

.card1 {
  background-color: #6EB806;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 30%;
}

.card2 {
  background-color: #36E059;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 30%;
}

.card3 {
  background-color: #00FF09;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 30%;
}

.herobox1 {
  flex: 2;
  /*background-color: #8D4E85;*/
}

.herobox2 {
  /*background-color: #684F96;*/
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bike Repair Shop</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssReset.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" alt="Website Logo">
      </div>
      <nav>
        <a href="">Book</a>
        <a href="">Online</a>
        <a href="">About</a>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
      </nav>

    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="herobox1">
        <h1>Mobile bike repairs </h1>
        <p>Many people have difficulty getting their bikes to a bike shop. We call to your office or home anywhere in greater Dublin.</p>
        <p>Fast, convenient bike servicing with up-front pricing. All without the hassle of taking your bike into a shop. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="herobox2">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" alt="Person servicing bike in Dublin">
      </div>
    </main>
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card1"></div>
      <div class="card2"></div>
      <div class="card3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: I want the logo and navigation to appear in a row on the header section.]

Comment: try comment your resetcss, leave just style.css

Comment: @Electro Voyager logo and navbar in same row.. working fine .. what do you want to do ?

Comment: Actually the nav content (here links <a> tags) should be on the righ side of the logo. Like in rows.

Comment: it's already on the right side...

Comment: @Electro Voyager I launched your code locally without restcss and it displays img and nav in same row as desired. Can you either comment resetCss or provide the code in that file? 

Also - up the Dubs!

Comment: without stylerss it will look like this https://ibb.co/gPqbxQT

Comment: give  `justify-content: space-between;` to header tag

Comment: `Justify-content: space-between` won't have the correct affect in this instance

Comment: Yes guys thanks, without the css reset it's work.

Comment: what thing make it works ?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this happens?? As per the study materials I added the cssreset to remove all default css effects. But for instructor video it's works. For me this bug occurred. Little confused, can anyone explain how to overcome this.

Comment: @Electro Voyager .. it's all about overriding  . .. generally code execute line by line ...short explanation

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a `div` around the texts and adding a `padding-top` seems to resolve it.

```
  <nav>
    <div style="padding-top: 18%;">
      <a href="">Book</a>
      <a href="">Online</a>
      <a href="">About</a>
      <a href="">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLmj568x/

Answer (score -1):

`header{ flex-direction: column; }`

Add this code to your CSS code.

Comment: The code works fine without cssreset and adding flex-direction: column with cssreset have no effect.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, finally with the help from this forum I understand my mistake. As you people said cssreset caused the trouble. I need to first  cssReset.css and then  my custom styles.css to get the correct effect. Otherwise the effect made using styles.css is overriden by cssReset.css A simple mistakes. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Note: [SO is not a forum](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)